# iOS Safari renders specific font not correctly

Tags: ios, text, fonts, safari

I need to use the font Machauer on my project. On desktop (Chrome/Safari) it renders correctly but not on iOS (iPhone/iPad).

Strangely on the download page of the font the same problem is happening - except for the textarea. The font is there displayed with all its details in the correct way. I wonder what is different there.

[The website with textarea](https://webfonts.ffonts.net/Machauer-Glas.font)

textarea displayed correctly:

[image: textarea correctly displayed]

this is how it renders outside the textarea:

[image: how it renders outside the textarea]

I tried different options like text-Rendering or font-smoothing - it had no impact on iOS Safari.

This how I specified the font and used it:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Machauer';
src: url(fonts/machauer.ttf) format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Machauer';
text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I tried some other solutions. I found [this](https://css-tricks.com/watch-your-font-weight/)

I just added font-weight: 100 to my h1 so the browser wont try to bolden the font artificially and knows it is wanted to stay thin (or in this specific case a decorative font).